Proof that if Steiner system $(t, k, n)$ exists, then so does $(t-1, k-1, n-1)$
Wikipedia page on Steiner systems states such argument:

If S(t, k, n) exists, then taking all blocks containing a specific element and discarding that element gives a derived system S(t−1, k−1, n−1). Therefore, the existence of S(t−1, k−1, n−1) is a necessary condition for the existence of S(t, k, n).

But it sounds completely wrong. We will end up with some blocks of $k-1$ elements (the ones where we removed the specific element) and some blocks of $k$ elements (the ones that didn't contain this element to begin with).

You have answered your own question, but here is some additional context anyway. There are (at least) three different standard "derived designs" that can be obtained from a given Steiner system (or design).
Notation: $S_\lambda(t, k, n)$ (where $t \le k \le n$) means a system of $k$-subsets (blocks) of an $n$-element set such that every $t$-set is contained in exactly $\lambda$ blocks. The case $\lambda=1$ is the case of Steiner systems. If $\lambda>1$ you can think of an $S_\lambda(t, k, n)$ system as a Steiner system with multiplicity. (It is also called a $t$-$(n, k, \lambda)$ design, but I find the order of parameters in this language unintuitive and hard to remember.)
Suppose you start with an $S_\lambda(t, k, n)$ system.

Take all the sets containing a given element and then discard that element from those sets. This gives a $S_\lambda(t-1, k-1, n-1)$ system.
This is the derived system under discussion.
This operation is akin to looking at the neighbourhood of a vertex in a graph.

Just decrease $t$ to $t-1$. This gives an $S_{\lambda'}(t-1, k, n)$ system where $\lambda'(k-t+1) = \lambda (n-t+1)$.

Take all the sets not containing a given element. This gives a $S_{\lambda''}(t-1, k, n-1)$ system where $\lambda'' = \lambda' - \lambda$.



I misunderstood. The solution is to first remove all blocks that do not contain that particular element and then remove the element from remaining blocks.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
